# HTML request to python?

Tags: javascript, python, php, html

Hi so I'm trying to write a cgi script in python that gets values from html input fields and prints accordingly. I've tried using chmod to get the python to be execuatable but somehow it isn't working and I'm getting a Internal server error at the **x.send** request. It has to be done this way so not looking for alternatives. My code looks like this.
HTML:

```
<h1>Login</h1>                       
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="lg_user" name="lg_uid">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="lg_pwd" name="lg_pass">
                <br/>
                <button type="submit" id="login_btn" onclick="loggingin()">Login</button>
                <div id="lg_test">Login</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loggingin(){
            var u=document.getElementById("lg_uid");
            var p=document.getElementById("lg_pass");
            try{
                x=new XMLHttpRequest();
                x.addEventListener("readystatechange", stateChange, false);
                x.open("POST","../cgi-bin/checkpass.py",true);
                x.send("lg_uid="+u+"&lg_pass="+p);
            }
            catch(exception){
                alert("Request failed");
            }
        }
        function stateChange(){
            if (x.readyState==4 && x.status==200)
            {
                sessionStorage.logstats
                if(sessionStorage.logstats==null || sessionStorage.logstats=="loggedOut")
                {
                    sessionStorage.logstats="loggedIn";
                    checkState();
                    //showPage("home_section");
                    //location.reload();
                }
                else if(sessionStorage.logstats=="loggedIn"){
                    sessionStorage.logstats="loggedOut";
                    checkState();
                    //showPage("home_section");
                    //location.reload();
                }
                document.getElementById("lg_test"),innerHTML=x.responseText;
                
            }
        }
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb
import csv

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
username = form.getvalue("lg_uid")
password = form.getvalue("lg_pass")

found=0

with open('users.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        if row[0] == username or password ==row[1]:
            found=1

print ("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
if found == 1:
    print ("<p>Your Password Matches</p>")
if username == "":
    print("<p>No usename provided</p>")
else:
    print ("<p>Wrong Usename or Password</p>")
```

Comment: Does it work with a simpler cgi script, e.g. one that only returns a static HTML without any logic? What web server are you using? Are there any error logs?

Comment: static HTML also isn't running. Not sure about the server. The error log is 500 Internal server error at the the x.send() line of the JavaScript

Comment: if it helps when I change the extension to .py from .cgi the entire python script is returned as the response text

Comment: @Argha - We need more details of your server, and your server configuration. This seems like an issue with the server - not the HTML or Python

Comment: Yeah I think you're right but I'm not privy to the server details but thanks knowing that it's a server side issue helps a lot